# Does "resize2fs" work like this?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I read how to use "resize2fs" but something is not very clear, would like to confirm if the following steps are correct. My goal is to do resizing without losing data. I can use rescue CD to boot first.

```
1. delete partition
2. re-create partition (with both starting and ending position changed)
3. resize2fs
```

like below,

```
# parted /dev/sda --script -- rm 3
# parted /dev/sda --script -- mkpart primary 80000 100000
# resize2fs /dev/sda3
```

My guess is "resize2fs" will automatically resize the file system according to the partition table, correct?

Thanks.

Comment: That looks right. Without arguements, resize2fs will take the entire partition. See man resizefs for details.